# Difference between WebPage and Article - Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

As there are a limited number of options available in Schema.org, I wonder whats the best schema to use when it doesn't fit into the other categories.  For example if I'm writing about a Car (assuming there is no car schema as I've not seen one) then should I use the Article or WebPage schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official documentation suggests three options:

> If you publish content of an unsupported type, you have three options:
>
> 1. Do nothing (don't mark up the content in any way). However, before you decide to do this, check to see if any of the types supported by schema.org - such as reviews, comments, images, or breadcrumbs - are relevant.
> 2. Use a less-specific markup type. For example, schema.org has no "Professor" type. However, if you have a directory of professors in your university department, you could use the "person" type to mark up the information for every professor in the directory.
> 3. If you are feeling ambitious, use the schema.org extension system to define a new type.

Also if you do not declare explicitly the type of a web page it is considered to be of http://schema.org/WebPage, that is the most general type that you can use in this case.

[Quote source](http://schema.org/docs/faq.html#12)

Answer (score -1):

(Schema.org has a type for cars, [`Car`](http://schema.org/Car), which is a `Product`. I’m using a parrot as example in this answer.)

You might want to [differentiate](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67802/17633) between the thing the page is about and the page.

You can mark up your page with `WebPage`, but that doesn’t convey what the page is about / what it contains. To denote that, you need another item that can be used as value for the [`about`](https://schema.org/about) / [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) property.

If Schema.org doesn’t offer a specific type, go up in the type hierarchy. There’s *always* a type that works: `Thing`. Or in other words: start at `Thing` and go down until you find the most specific type. See [my answer on Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92108/17633) with more details.

So a page (`WebPage`) about a specific parrot (`Thing`) could be marked up like this:

```html
<body typeof="schema:WebPage">
  <article property="schema:mainEntity" typeof="schema:Thing">
  </article>
</body>
```

And if possible, it can be a good idea to use suitable specific types from other vocabularies (e.g., from animal or even parrot ontologies) in addition to the Schema.org types. For example, you could use the [`Parrot` type from DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/resource/Parrot):

```html
<body typeof="schema:WebPage" prefix="dbpedia: http://dbpedia.org/resource/">
  <article property="schema:about" typeof="schema:Thing dbpedia:Parrot">
  </article>
</body>
```